# How to differentiate between checked and selected items in a list

Tags: verbs, synonyms

In computer terms, sometimes there is a need to distinguish between items in a list that are checked (e.g. lists that have a checkbox next to them) and items that are selected (e.g. user clicks on one or more rows in a table) because sometimes items can be checked and selected at the same time. What are some other words that can be used to describe them so that it is clear and unambiguous for other languages as well, because apparently checked and ticked are confusing between English and American speakers.

I am looking for terms like 'marked', 'flagged', keeping in mind that they would ideally also serve as a noun and verb.

Yes, it is one of those questions that gets stuck between both worlds. The reason to ask it here is because it is something that needs to be shown to a normal user, and that they would have to understand it. To programmers it doesn't matter as long as there is some rule to define the different behaviours (as you see on the screen).

I wanted to know whether the term is appropriate for other languages, and also whether it is generally clear or slightly unambiguous or unintuitive.

[image]

Comment: Should probably belong in UX.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does "checked" item mean? To select is to "choose" To check could mean in your case, "confirm".

Comment: Are you concerned to describe the state of checkboxes, radio buttons or select elements differently when used in coding, or are you concerned to provide general instructions for a user when using them as part of a form? Obviously the states of those elements are checked, unchecked, selected etc., so it wouldn't be helpful to change those.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs in UX.stackexchange.com 

Comment: @TrevorD, while the subject may be related to programming, it is a question about English usage.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I did think about that - but also thought that the programming site might have better ideas for the desired naming that ELU.

Comment: Can you not look at other websites to see what they are called on other sites?

Comment: @TrevorD, I see, this poor question is stuck between two worlds! :-)

Comment: "checked item" vs. "highlighted item". Describe what it looks like.

Comment: @TrevorD, I am asking this question here because I want general public to answer it rather than programmers and UX designers. Also, it is a way to describe the action and state, so you don't see this normally on a website or software.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify exactly what you are asking and why (incorporating relevant parts of your comment and any other pertinent info). Then you can ask for it to be re-opened, but that is unlikely without you first editing the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Checked" is American for "ticked".

Comment: @TrevorD Thanks, I later *checked* in the dictionary!

Comment: @MichaelLai I'm not sure... maybe someone can confirm. But you could ask in meta if the mods would consider opening your question, explaining your reasons and asking what changes you should make in order for your question to comply with the criteria requested.

Answer (score 5):

The terminology I would use would be checked (or marked) and highlighted. The checkbox is checked and the row next to it can be highlighted. Both of these terms can serve as a noun and a verb.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Comment: +1. Same thing I would say, except I’d be more likely to use ‘ticked’ than ‘marked’, which would be ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it either

> one active row is assumed ⇒ **active**, **current** <strike>or **hovered**</strike> item
>
> multiple active rows are assumed ⇒ **activated** items

---

**UX Thoughts**

To my mind **highlighted** fits only when it exposes that something's been highlighted and is insignificant in terms of data processing workflow (I mean it may be quite meaningless in terms of your application's **domain logic**).

So if I want user to be able to **include** (check) preferences and activate some of them (right now) I use **activated preferences**.